# If $3^ y \mid (2^x)+1$, then how must $x$ and $y$ relate to each other

Tags: number-theory

Say we know that for some integers $x$ and $y$ that ${2^y}\equiv -1\pmod {3^y}$. Then is there anything we can know about how $x$ and $y$ relate. More specifically is there any function $y=f(x)$ such that the $x$ and $y$ relating in this way are all of the solutions to the above congruence?

Comment: There's a typo in your question -- I think you mean $2^x$ but you wrote $2^y$. But in any case, there won't be any function like that, because there will be multiple $y$ for the same $x$. For example, when $x = 3$, both $y = 1$ and $y = 2$ are solutions. And maybe even more striking -- $y = 0$ is a solution for all $x$!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [LTE](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lifting_The_Exponent_Lemma) lemma

$$y \le v_3(2^x+1)=v_3(2+1)+v_3(x)=1+v_3(x)$$Thus $y \le v_3(x)+1$. That is all we can say about their relation.